# Transfer BTC to wrong address

Tags: cross-chain-recovery

I made a BTC transferred from the Luno exchange into my CEX exchange account, but I accidentally entered the CEX's BCH (bitcoin cash) wallet address instead of BTC and Luno did not blocked this receiving address.

Now, the transfer had transaction confirmation in blockchain public ledger

My CEX's BCH or BTC wallet did not reflected this deposit. Please advice me if any action for the recovery and how to make the deposit reflected in the CEX's wallet. I already raised urgent support tickets to both of the exchange, no reply from them yet.

Thanks in advance for you guys advices

Answer (score 0):

contact CEX and explain to them, they should be able to give you the money since they control the private key.

Comment: Which party should able to rectify this issue?  Sending exchange or the receiving exchange? What will happen in case if they can't release the private key?  https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2071446.0